# Get element offset position and do something

Tags: jquery, css, function, offset

I need to show overlay/lightbox window on my page depend on action input position. Below is my JQuery code, can enybody help me?

```
$('input.proxy').click(function() {
    $('div.proxy').fadeIn('600', function() {
        var r = ('input.proxy').attr('offsetTop');
        $('div.proxy').css('margin-top', r + 'px' );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(".rightpage").offset().top` to get the offset position.

Comment: You changed de .rightpage to input.proxy? I`ve tested here and it works fine

Comment: var r = $('div.proxy').offset().top() ok i set like this and with var r = $('div.proxy').offset().top it's work, thx